# How can I display my object which contains color codes?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to this community so I hope my first Question will not give you a straight facepalm or so ;)
I've just started coding, I really love it and damn have a lot to learn, so now I'm here!

About my Question, I have this object in a .js file.

```
colors = {

    '#7595AE':      'rgb(139,166,194)', 
    '#ACC4D4':      'rgb(279,195,214)',     
    '#E6B0A0':      'rgb(230,176,160)', 
    '#D3705E':      'rgb(200,26,33)'        
}
```

And I wish to display it kind of like an ul/li on my HTML-file/Website:
**Example output, click me**:
[image: **Example output, click me**]

YES in the example, the colorcodes are as u can see just random values ;)

Comment: Please share an attempt at solving the problem, as a [mcve], with us.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to create an element for both key and value? A simple loop would do it.

```js
const colors = {
  '#7595AE': 'rgb(139,166,194)',
  '#ACC4D4': 'rgb(279,195,214)',
  '#E6B0A0': 'rgb(230,176,160)',
  '#D3705E': 'rgb(200,26,33)'
}

const list = document.querySelector("#list");
for (let property in colors) {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerText = property;
  div.style.backgroundColor = property;
  let div2 = document.createElement("div");
  div2.innerText = colors[property];
  div2.style.backgroundColor = colors[property];
  li.appendChild(div);
  li.appendChild(div2);
  list.appendChild(li);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: Yes Sir, 2 elements for both "key and value"!   i'll try to code it out, and let you know!  thanks a lot for this my friend :) !!  you will hear from me

Answer (score 0):

Hi welcome to stackoverflow :)

For your question you can make something like that :

For a little explanation, the first loop it's to create dynamically all the `li`

the second loop, it's to assign the particular color at only one `li` element, and the same for the text, for make this I use a `ES6` element, `Object.values` who return all value from object, and `Object.keys` return all the keys form an `Object`

```js
const colors = {
    '#7595AE':      'rgb(139,166,194)', 
    '#ACC4D4':      'rgb(279,195,214)',     
    '#E6B0A0':      'rgb(230,176,160)', 
    '#D3705E':      'rgb(200,26,33)'        
};

const container = document.querySelector('.list-container');
const li = document.createElement('li');

for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(colors).length; i++) {
 const li = document.createElement('li');
  container.appendChild(li);
}


const list = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].style.backgroundColor = Object.values(colors)[i];
  list[i].innerHTML = `${Object.keys(colors)[i]} ${Object.values(colors)[i]}`;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list-container"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry if my Question was not specific enough, but as Chris LI sayed i want to display both value and key in two separate elements :) . I'll go through it and let you know how/if i solved it, also thanks to you for your help!